# Can't copy NSArray to std::vector using ARC

Tags: nsarray, automatic-ref-counting, stdvector

I am trying to Objective-C++ to copy the contents of an NSArray into an std::vector in a project that is using automatic reference counting.
When I write this:

```
NSArray* array;

...

std::vector<id> buffer;
buffer.reserve(array.count);

[array getObjects:&buffer[0] range:NSMakeRange(0, array.count)];
```

The call to `getObjects:range:` results in this **error**:
`Cannot initialize a parameter of type '__unsafe_unretained id *`' with an `rvalue` of type `'__strong id *`'

Some searching on the web indicated that maybe a `__bridge` cast was needed. Using this code:
    `[array getObjects:(__bridge id*)&buffer[0] range:NSMakeRange(0, array.count)];`

Results in this **error**:
`Incompatible types casting '__strong id *' to '__strong id *' with a __bridge cast`

What is needed to that the array objects can be copied into the vector?

Comment: It looks like I've solved it. Here's what I did that made to code compile successfully:

 __unsafe_unretained id* data = reinterpret_cast<__unsafe_unretained id*>(&buffer[0]);
 
 [self getObjects:data range:NSMakeRange(0, self.count)];

Answer (score 3):

I got my code to work by doing this;

```
std::vector<__unsafe_unretained id> buffer(array.count);
[array getObjects:&buffer[0] range:NSMakeRange(0, array.count)];
```

The vector is a local object on the stack inside a method, so it goes out of scope and won't need to hold onto the array elements